# Active - Passive DR Strategy for OpenShift v4.x

Tags: openshift, f5, openshift-enterprise

We have OpenShift v4.3 deployed across two separate datacenter (Prod and DR) on active/passive strategy. In the event of disaster in Prod, our GTM will switch traffic to DR.

Prod: `*.apps.cluster1.domain.com`

DR: `*.apps.cluster2.domain.com`

But how can we implement a main OCP endpoint: `*.apps.main_cluster_name.domain.com` so that it won't change on user side even after the fail over.

Comment: You can create a vanity route on each cluster. For example, `myapp.mycompany.com`

Comment: Can you share any document showing how it can be done? Thanks